# SQL Statement: Improper OR validation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I have a problem with my SQL Syntax:

- I have a table with tickets, this is from my PHP MyAdmin:

[image]

But don't understand what is wrong with my SQL Syntax at the top of the image. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: SO prefer text not image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `or` condition have to change like below

```
 select * from ticket where type=1 and cid=72351 and (state=1 or state=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` selector is the culprit. I propose an alternative solution to your approach:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE type=1 AND cid=72351 AND (state IN (0,1))
```

If you ever need to quickly expand the search to include a greater range of `type`, you can simply add the number, rather than a whole expression. Hope that helps.